# Why doesn't data fetched in an $http call, always show up/get used outside it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, data-binding, angularjs-digest

I am sometimes, and very very randomly, not able to use data received in an $http call. The data thus received will bind to the variable in which it is received, but it won't transfer to another variable. For example, below {{avariable}} shows up in the HTML page (it stops being null and displays the data from the server) but {{anumber}} does not change from 0 to the new data (even though I do $scope.anumber = $scope.avariable). Sometimes this problem is solved by assigning the equality in the $http call itself and not later, but this time it did not work that way either. I imagine this has something to do with digest, eval cycles right? I don't necessarily understand them well or how they work in this context. Though, I do use $timeout when necessary.

Everything is working on the Rails/backend side - I checked by directly going to the URL in my browser. Also of course, as mentioned earlier, {{avariable}} does change from null to the server data.

AngularJS code:

```
myangularmodule.controller('appcontroller', function($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $location, $state, $timeout, $http) {

$scope.avariable = null;

$scope.anumber = 0;


$scope.ihappenwhenthatbuttonispressed {

$timeout(function(){
 $http.get('/employees/getthisdata/' + value + '.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.avariable = data.avariable;

    });
}, 5);

         $scope.anumber = $scope.avariable;



};


});
```

My HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</head>

 <body ng-app="myangularmodule">
  <div ng-controller="appcontroller">

    <button ng-click="ihappenwhenthatbuttonispressed(anumber)">
         Click me
   </button>

     {{avariable}}
     {{anumber}}

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you posted is not valid Javascript. Also, `$timeout` is not needed when using `$http`.

Comment: `$http.get` would be asynchronous - therefore the success function probably runs after (well after) the line of code after the end of the $http.get block

Answer (score 0):

This is because AJAX calls in Javascript are asynchronous.  You are calling an http request, and then immediately setting `$scope.anumber = $scope.avariable` and not waiting for the http response.  So when you click the button the first time, you are essentially setting `$scope.anumber = null`.  When the http response is received, `$scope.avariable` is being set as your `data.variable` and then the function exits.

If you want to update both, you need something like this:

```
$http.get('/employees/getthisdata/' + value + '.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.avariable = data.avariable;
    updateANumber();
});
function updateANumber(){
    $scope.anumber = $scope.avariable;
}
```

Comment: _This is because Javascript is asynchronous_ not quite. AJAX (usually) is, so are the functions called in setTimeOut and setInterval and other places ... but saying "javascript is asynchronous" is not quite accurate

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
$http.get('/employees/getthisdata/' + value + '.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.avariable = data.avariable;
    $scope.anumber = $scope.avariable;
});
```

The timeout part isn't needed.